# Spring @Autowired not working for eagerly initialized beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, spring-3

I am trying to write a service-oriented application.

I have a been called `memory` defined as such:

```java
package com.example.assets;

//imports ignored

@Resource
public class Memory {
}
```

And I have a service been called `memoryHandler` defined as such:

```java
package com.example.service;

//imports ignored

@Service
public class MemoryHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Memory memory;

    public void execute() {
        //do something with memory
    }
}
```

There is also another class, which is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```java
package com.example.service;

//imports ignored

@Component
public class PostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.getBeansOfType(MemoryHandler.class, false, true);
    }
}
```

Which prematurely looks up the bean, `memoryHandler`, leaving it instantiated` but not autowired. However, I want the bean to be autowired before it is fetched by the factory.

In my Main class I have written:

```java
package com.example.service;

//imports ignored

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
        context.getBean(MemoryHandler.class).execute();
    }

}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` on the line I work with the memory. I replaced the above declaration with a setter injection, and upon tracing realized that the injection never occurs.

I have changed the annotations on both components to `Service`, `Repository`, and `Component` and also have tried replacing `Autowired` with `Resource` to no avail.

What am I missing here? I have read all the questions that have shown up in my search for an answer, and none of them helps me (I got the tip about using `Resouce` annotations there).

Needless to say, I have not missed annotation configuration for my beans:

```java
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
```

Moreover, autowiring works just fine when autowired beans are defined in the XML configuration file, and not via annotations.

I am using Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Annotating a class with `@Service` annotation and Autowiring that in another class did work for me. Amazed that it's not working for you.

Comment: Yes. I was wrong. The problem comes from the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` bean. You can check out my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the implementation of the PostProcessor is the key:

Instead of:

```
public class PostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
```

I will have to write:

```
public class PostProcessor implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

This ensures that the context will be fully populated before it is post-processed, which in my case works just fine. But I am wondering if there is another way to do this, using the usual `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` interface?